# Can Someone Help Me To Find What Is Wrong With This Java Programming

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age =56 ;

     ( if age<= 20) ;
            switch (age) {
                case 11:
                    System.out.println("You Are 11 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    System.out.println("You Are 12 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 13:
                    System.out.println("You Are 13 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 14:
                    System.out.println("You Are 14 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 15:
                    System.out.println("You Are 15 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 16:
                    System.out.println("You Are 16 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 17:
                    System.out.println("You Are 17 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 18:
                    System.out.println("You Are 18 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 19:
                    System.out.println("You Are 19 Year Old");
                    break;
                case 20:
                    System.out.println("You Are 20 Year Old");
                    break;
```

I am getting an Unreachable Statement Error In Intellij can someone give me guidance as to why I am getting this error ?  Have tried to realign the codes but nothing seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: concentrate on syntax

Comment: You have not posted your complete program, and what you have posted isn't legal syntax.  I can't tell what statement is unreachable.  Also, IntelliJ should tell you which line it thinks is unreachable; please share that information with us.

Comment: Get rid of the switch statement and use a format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:
IF condition is not written properly.

```
package com.art;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age = 56;
        if (age <= 20) {
            switch (age) {
            case 11:
                System.out.println("You Are 11 Year Old");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("You Are 12 Year Old");
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.println("You Are 13 Year Old");
                break;
            case 14:
                System.out.println("You Are 14 Year Old");
                break;
            case 15:
                System.out.println("You Are 15 Year Old");
                break;
            case 16:
                System.out.println("You Are 16 Year Old");
                break;
            case 17:
                System.out.println("You Are 17 Year Old");
                break;
            case 18:
                System.out.println("You Are 18 Year Old");
                break;
            case 19:
                System.out.println("You Are 19 Year Old");
                break;
            case 20:
                System.out.println("You Are 20 Year Old");
                break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Age is more than 20");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What shouldn't compile in your code is  -

```
( if age<= 20) ;
```

which might rather have been thought of as -

```
if(age<= 20) {    
//proper parenthesis which should be marked by IntelliJ as well
// the semi-colon though is not incorrect but terminates the if without any block to execute in your case
```

---

Please do note, that you're previously setting the value of `age` as 56 and hence the if condition should evaluate to `false` not executing the block within.